# data curation system and manual data management

Tags: database, database-design, spreadsheet, rdbms, data-warehouse

I'm looking for a solution that may already exist; however, I'm unable to identify what the name would be for this type of system and hence unable to find one.  I was hoping someone could identify what I'm looking for.

I have data that get's manually and automatically curated.  The manually curated data is often updated and is managed in excel or some form of spreadsheet.  The automated system generates spreadsheets for more manual curation.  I'm looking for a RDBMS based software solution that would allow data entry employees or curators to create data schemas with little DB experience (using a GUI).  In addition they can make schema changes and modifications to the data set.  The data then can be deployed to a number of sources which essentially triggers an ETL daemon to fetch changes and persist then to the destination source (staging, production, etc).

Here are some requirements:

1. System should be user friendly and be accessible to non-dba or non-programmer (friendly GUI)
2. System should allow users to create and alter schemas in the DB
3. System should have an API that developers can use to automatically curate data
4. System should have an API that developers can use to write ETL scripts that fetch ONLY changes with data (for quick updates and imports)
5. Bonus: system can allow users/curators to deploy to admin controlled sources

I think that gives a general picture of what I'm looking for.  I'm sure that some kind of similar system must already exist.  The principle of a data warehouse and ETL process is NOT novel by any means.

**Does anyone know what kind of software/system I'm looking for?**

A name or phrase that can help me research systems that server this purpose.

**Bonus:  does anyone know of any "affordable" solutions?**

Answer (score 0):

We use an automation / ETL solution in my workplace called Foxtrot. I'm not in IT and use it fairly regularly; it is basically point and click to write scripts that automate all sorts of things. I believe there are two flavors: one that automates in Windows only and another that automates in Windows and web. You can find more here: http://www.enablesoft.com/foxtrot-automation-software/

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar ETL services such as Pentaho...  What I'm looking for would allow the user to manage the data schema and records with an intuitive UI...  ETL will be part of the process but is NOT the core feature.  That could even be a custom script.  More or less though I'm looking for something that will give us what has been added or updated rather than the raw DB (like GIT).